# Applying tactics to local subgoals of a semicolon chain in Coq

Tags: coq

Suppose we had the definitions

```
Inductive sillyA : nat -> Prop :=
| sA0 : sillyA 0
| sA1 : sillyA 1.

Inductive sillyB : nat -> Prop :=
| sB0 : sillyB 0
| sB1 : sillyB 1.

Inductive sillyC (n : nat) : Prop :=
| sC0 : sillyA n -> sillyC n
| sC1 : sillyA n -> sillyC n.
```

and wanted to prove

```
Theorem silly : forall n, sillyC n -> sillyB n.
```

A simple proof by case analysis would be

```
intros. inversion H; inversion H0.
apply sB0. apply sB1.
apply sB0. apply sB1.
```

But there is an obvious repetition of `apply sB0. apply sB1.` here.

Question: What would be the best way to factor it out, short of defining a new tactics notation?

Using `T; [T1 | ... Tn]` cannot help, because

```
intros. inversion H; inversion H0;
[apply sB0 | apply sB1].
```

has a wrong number of tactics, and the correct form

```
intros. inversion H; inversion H0;
[apply sB0 | apply sB1 | apply sB0 | apply sB1].
```

is not an improvement at all. What we need is a tactic that is similar to `T; [T1 | ... Tn]`, but applies `[T1 | ... Tn]` only to subgoals generated by the immediately preceding tactic `T`, not the entire semicolon chain. If we had such a tactic `T; <T1 | ... Tn>`, we could further shorten the proof above to

```
intros. inversion H; inversion H0;
<apply sB0 | apply sB1>.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping will do it:

```
Theorem silly : forall n, sillyC n -> sillyB n.
intros. inversion H; (inversion H0; [apply sB0 | apply sB1]).
```

Comment: Would you mind answering a little follow-up? I'm in a situation where tactics `T`, `Ta`, and `Tb` branch into 2 subgoals. I want to first apply `T`, apply `Ta` to the first subgoal from `T`, and `Tb` to the second. And then apply tactic `T1` to the first subgoals from *both* `Ta` and `Tb`, and `T2` to the second. So without `;` the proof would be `T. Ta. T1. T2. Tb. T1. T2.` Can this also be refactored by grouping? The best I could get was `T; [(Ta; [T1 | T2]) | (Tb; [T1 | T2])].`, whereas I was hoping for something like `T; ([Ta | Tb]; [T1 | T2]).` (It doesn't work, but you get the idea.)

Comment: "It doesn't work, but you get the idea." I have to say that I  don't. I suggest you post a new question, and also that you learn about other tacticals like `repeat`, `try`, and `||`, all of which might help.